# Package Validation in Enterprise Architect does not warn about Deployment Specification Instance deployments to Nodes or Devices

Tags: enterprise-architect

I have a question about Package Validation in Enterprise Architect. According to the [UML Specification v2.5.1](http://www.omg.org/spec/UML/2.5.1) section 19.2.3 "Semantics" paragraph 3:

> DeploymentSpecifications can only be associated with DeploymentTargets that are
>   ExecutionEnvironments

However, when I connect a `Deployment Specification Instance` to a `Node` or `Device` via a `Deployment Connector` as shown in the following figure ...

[image]

... no warning or error is raised when I invoke `Validate Current Package`:

[image]

I enabled all options in the `Model Validation Configuration` dialogue:

[image: Model Validation Configuration]

## Question

1. How can I enforce that behaviour in Enterprise Architect to only generate conforming UML?
2. Or how at least can I get a warning that the result if non-UML compliant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard validation rules in EA only validate a limited set of UML syntax rules.

You could report this as a [bug](https://www.sparxsystems.com/support/forms/bug_report.html), and let Sparx add this rule, but you'll need to be patient.

As an alternative you can write your [own validation rules](https://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/13.5/automation/model_validation_broadcasts.html) that can be executed by the standard model validation. This will require you to write an add-in and validation code for each rule.

Or you can use the open source [validation framework](https://github.com/GeertBellekens/Enterprise-Architect-Toolpack/tree/master/EAValidator) we developed, where you can define rules using SQL queries.

Comment: As discussed, I submitted a bug report at Sparx  with CaseId 18058962. today, I got a confirmation, that this will be fixed in the next build of EA14 (1421).